# Android GPS position - remove updates

Tags: java, android, gps, locationlistener

I just can't remove location listening in my app. I'm using this in onCreate method:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```

and this in my onPause/onStop/onDestroy method:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

But when I close my app, the satelite icon is still there. Why?

Comment: Are you using Google maps? are you using any listeners with Google maps?

Comment: No Google maps, only android.location.LocationListener and so on. I don't need a map, only GPS coordinates.

Comment: What's the scope of *locationListener*

Comment: Have you confirmed that when you kill the app's processes and services that the GPS icon turns off?

Comment: Your code looks fine as is. Please post more context to when / how you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by a new onResume method:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
}
```